# Laravel recursive partials view categories

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to be able to display infinitive ammount of subcategories in my view for example I have in my blade view

```
@if (count($projects) > 0)
    <ul>
      @foreach ($projects as $project)
         @include('partials.project', $project)
      @endforeach
    </ul>
@else
    @include('partials.projects-none')
@endif
```

partials.project

```
<li>{{ $project['name'] }}</li>
 @if (count($project['children']) > 0)
     <ul>
       @foreach($project['children'] as $project)
         @include('partials.project', $project)
       @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

projects-none

```
 You have no projects!
```

but after I enter I get error message

Undefined variable: projects but when I dd($projects) i get data from database

Controller code

```
  $projects= Projects::all(); (I tried it even with pluck but it didn't work)
  return view('projects')->with('projects', $projects);
```

I have added dd($projects) after if loop in view to see if I'm receiving it all and I was receiving it;

Comment: Where did you try `dd($projects)`, in the controller? Also post your controller function code here.

Comment: I added code from controller

Comment: from what line the error raise from?

Comment: first line in partials.projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I. With your "messy way"**
*- Change*

```
@include('partials.project', $project)
```

*- To*

```
@include('partials.project', ['project'=>$project])
```

**II. Try this better way. I though** 
*- All in partials.projects*

```
<ul>
      @each ('partials.project', $projects, 'project', 'partials.projects-none')
</ul>
```

**Similar to partials.project. I lot of code will be saved.**